# Using Service as "Factory" to Return Different Bean Implementations

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, factory

I want to use this type of service class in my Spring application as a "factory" to return the correct implementation of DocumentProcessor in response to a supplied enum value.

I'm doing this because I want to set up each processor itself as a component and take advantage of autowiring vs just creating new instances when each processor is needed.

I haven't really seen this done anywhere else - Can anyone tell me if this is a bad idea?

All "TypeXYZDocumentProcessor" classes are extensions of an abstract "DocumentProcessor" base class.

```
@Service
public class DocumentProcessorService {

  @Autowired
  TypeXDocumentProcessor typeXDocumentProcessor;

  @Autowired
  TypeYDocumentProcessor typeYDocumentProcessor;

  @Autowired
  TypeZDocumentProcessor typeZDocumentProcessor;

  public DocumentProcessor getDocumentProcessor(DocumentType docType) {
    switch (docType) {
      case TYPE_X:
        return typeXDocumentProcessor;
      case TYPE_Y:
        return typeYDocumentProcessor;
      case TYPE_Z:
        return typeZDocumentProcessor;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}  

@Component
public class TypeXDocumentProcessor extends DocumentProcessor {
  ...
}

public abstract class DocumentProcessor {
  ...
}
```

Comment: "TypeXYZDocumentProcessor"  will be three beans in spring application contenxt,you can return bean by applictionContext.getBean() method.

Comment: First of all, we don't @Autowire implementations, but abstractions. How your XYZ beans are defined?

Comment: I think it would be better to give the processors a method returning the type they can process, then have the factory bean iterate through all beans and filter by type. There's a method to get that list (in the spring context IIRC).

Comment: @medKHELIFI Added the XYZ type bean definition for clarity.

Comment: `getDocumentProcessor` can't be static if it wants to access instance fields

Comment: I already did **exactly** the same thing that you do on a past project. Works well and is simple to understand, but I also have this doubt about if could exist a better approach. I was using EJB 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

This is my proposition, I used Interface instead of abstract class, but if you really need an abstract class you can return on it.

```
@Service
public class DocumentProcessorService {

  @Autowired
  // you can add here for examlpe a @Qualifier("typeXDocumentProcessor"),
  // then name your variable whatever you want.
  DocumentProcessor typeXDocumentProcessor;

  @Autowired
  DocumentProcessor typeYDocumentProcessor;

  @Autowired
  DocumentProcessor typeZDocumentProcessor;

  public DocumentProcessor getDocumentProcessor(DocumentType docType) {
    switch (docType) {
      case TYPE_X:
        return typeXDocumentProcessor;
      case TYPE_Y:
        return typeYDocumentProcessor;
      case TYPE_Z:
        return typeZDocumentProcessor;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}  

@Component
public class TypeXDocumentProcessor implements DocumentProcessor {
  ...
}
@Component
public class TypeYDocumentProcessor implements DocumentProcessor {
  ...
}
@Component
public class TypeZDocumentProcessor implements DocumentProcessor {
  ...
}

public interface class DocumentProcessor {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also do something like this. I've modified your abstract class `DocumentProcessor` to include the DocumentType.
Code is not tested or compiled.

This way, you can keep introducing more processors types and not touch the processor service at all.

```
@Service
public class DocumentProcessorService {

  @Autowired
  List<DocumentProcessor> documentProcessors;

  public DocumentProcessor getDocumentProcessor(DocumentType docType) {
    return documentProcessors.stream().filter(e -> e.getDocType().equals(docType)).findFirst().get();
  }
}

@Component
public class TypeXDocumentProcessor extends DocumentProcessor {

  public TypeXDocumentProcessor() {
    super(TYPE_X);
  }
}

// More Types...

public abstract class DocumentProcessor {
  ...

  DocumentType docType; 

  public DocumentProcessor(DocumentType docType) {
    this.docType = docType;
  }
  DocumentType getDocType() {
    return docType;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose going about this a different way. Let's replace `switch` or `if` blocks with polymorfism (not tested):

```
public enum DocumentType {

    TYPE_X("typeXDocumentProcessor"),
    TYPE_y("typeYDocumentProcessor");

    private DocumentProcessor processor;
    private final String beanName;

    DocumentType (String beanName){
      this.beanName = beanName;
    }
    public String process(){
        return processor.process();
    }


    @Component
    public static class DocumentTypeInjector {
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {
            for (DocumentType dt : EnumSet.allOf(DocumentType.class))
               dt.processor = context.getBean(dt.beanName)
        }
    }
}
```

And then your service won't need the `getDocumentProcessor` method at all. You would just have a `process` method for example, calling the `process` of the current enum instance